# `&quot;` not becoming quotation mark when output

Tags: php, html, quotes

My quotation marks, when converted to `&quot;` by `htmlentities()` are not turning back into actual quotation marks when output after being stored in the [Postgres] database. Please help - this is time sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you possibly calling htmlentities() twice (perhaps once before display by accident?), and hence making it actually `&amp;quote;`?

Comment: Thanks a lot - I was calling it twice by mistake.

Comment: A textbox will. <pre> won't, obviously.